# If Child or Grandchild of Page

Tags: templates

I'm serving a different header in Wordpress depending what section you are within the site, 'residential' , 'business' or other by using the following code. Although i need to extend it to work with grandchildren as well, so another level down.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Package
*/ 
if (is_page('business') || $post->post_parent=="17")
{
get_header('business');
}
else if (is_page('residential') || $post->post_parent=="19")
{
get_header('residential');
}
else 
{
get_header();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) will return the full parent page ID hierarchy for a given page ID which you could check against.

Answer (score -1):

You can count post ancestor like this

$count = count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));

The results means:

2= grandchild

1= child

0=parent